# Characters being ignored when typing in a text field

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am having an issue with characters being ignored when typing in a rich text field. This only seems to be an issue in IE8 and IE9. For example I have typed "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" four times and this is what is displayed in the rich text field.

```
the quick brown fx jump over the lazy dog
the quckbrown f umps over the azy dog
the quick rown fox jumps over the azy dog
the quck brown fox jumps ove the lazydog
```

I first assumed there may be some javascript running in the background attached to the keypress event (perhaps for spellcheck) which wasn't completing in time for the next keypress but have had no luck tracking it down. I have tried on multiple computers and all have this issue.

Comment: This is very strange.  Are all the computers you've tried identical Windows enterprise installations?  Perhaps you can try on a totally different brand of a machine (e.g. if the issue occurs with HPs, try reproducing on a Lenovo or Dell).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We noticed this weird problem with some of our users on Tridion SP1 in RTF fields. I do not recollect that we had issue with Normal TextFields.

Check this Hotfix if it helps : CM_2011.1.0.77763

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1/index.aspx (login to SDL Tridion World and go to Hotfixes to download this hotfix).

Comment: When I click the link nothing happens and when I manually save the contents of the link there is nothing in the zip file.

Comment: Btw they are RTF fields. My mistake

Comment: You need to login to sdltridionworld.com web site to download the hotfix. Update the link so it gets you to login page then check for the hotfix  to download.